# What are the differences between Nonlinear ModelFit and GeneralizedLinearModelFit, and how to get MLE out of each?

Tags: fitting

I would like to know the practical differences and implications between `NonlinearModelFit` and `GeneralizedLinearModelFit`. As I understand it if one wants to get errors out of a fit, the best way seems to be to use maximum likelihood estimation (MLE), whereby for a given parameter being scanned the ci-squares for each parameter value are plotted -- giving a parabolic function, one takes the minima of this and adds 1, the corresponding values for the parabolic curves at this point are give the error in this parameter.

I remember reading in a post on here that `GeneralizedLinearModelFit` is the best way to go to get our MLE, but I can't figure out how, and, I don't know why (assuming this to be the case).

So:

1. What are te differences between `NonlinearModelFit` and
   `GeneralizedLinearModelFit`.
2. When should one use them, is it valid to use `GeneralizedLinearModelFit` in all cases?
3. How can one get MLE estimates for each fit parameter value for both `GeneralizedLinearModelFit` and `NonlinearModelFit` (if possible) in Mathematica?

Comment: `NonlinearModelFit` is the more general fitting function of the two. It can fit any functional relationship whereas `GeneralizedLinearModelFit` is specialised for exponential families. Both functions return a `FittedModel` object that can be queried for fit diagnostics (e.g., by evaluating `fit["ParameterConfidenceIntervals"]`).

Comment: I think you're mixing up a few terms.  You'll get MLE's out of both.  If you have Gaussian errors, there's likely no reason to use `GeneralizedLinearModelFit` (as `LinearModelFit` will likely be much more efficient and doesn't require starting values).   It's not clear that your use of "errors" means "residuals" or "standard errors of the parameters".  Asking "What are the differences between nonlinear regression and generalized linear models?" at CrossValidated would get you more of the statistical details.  And there's no need to deal with chi-squares.

Comment: @JimB I was hoping you might throw your two cents in! As I undertsand it if you extract a fit paramter from a fit, the better method of getting the error in this fit parameter is MLE -- or at least the more modern convention -- as opposed to using a weighted fit and using the correlation matrix. Could you tell me how to get MLE from `NonlinearModelFit`?

Comment: Yes, just look at the estimated coefficients: `nlm["BestFitParameters"]`, for example if the output is stored in `nlm`.  And MLE is not necessarily always better.  MLE generally has better or at least known properties as the sample size tends towards infinity.  (And "better" doesn't necessarily mean "good".)  One advantage of using MLE is that one can get (with just a little additional effort) an estimate of the associated standard errors.  For other methods one might have to use a bootstrap to get appropriate estimates of standard errors which can be more costly in terms of computer time.

Comment: @JimB Thanks, informative as always!